# Kafka: does retired records affect offsets?

Tags: apache-kafka

At some point of time there was a number `x` representing offset of some record `A` in some Kafka partition. After `A` comes `B` with its offset equals `x + 1`. Some time later `A` is taken by a retention policy due to expiration; does it mean that `B` is no longer at the `x + 1` position, but went one step back (to take `A`'s place) and thus became `x`? If so, is there a valid and reliable way to track not-yet-retired records by their ids to be able to get them rapidly, bypassing other records in corresponding partition?

Simplier question: **are offsets unique values that never change, even if some records moved away by some retention policy**?

Comment: No, a message offset stays the same if prior ones are purged. Yes, they are unique and never change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, offsets are unique per Topic-partition and never change due to retention or otherwise